# SQL Server query to extract all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've two database tables, one called "Headers" and one called "Rows".
The structure is:

```
Header: IDPK | Description
Row:    IDPK | IDPK_Header | Item_ID | Qty
```

I need to do a query that says: "From a Header, IDPK find another header that have the same number of rows and the same item ID and quantity".

For example:

```
Header             Rows
IDPK  Description  IDPK    Item_ID    Qty
 1    'Test1'       1        'A'      10
 1    'Test1'       2        'B'      20
 2    'Test2'       3        'A'      10
 2    'Test2'       4        'B'      20
 3    'Test3'       5        'A'      5
 3    'Test3'       6        'B'      20
 4    'Test4'       7        'A'      10
```

Header `Test1` match `Test2` but not `Test3` and `Test4`

The problem is that the number of rows must be exactly the same. I try with `ALL` operator but without luck.

How I can do the query with an eye for the performance? The two tables can be very huge (~500.000 records).

Comment: I guess there might be an error in your IDBK column in Rows... the values 5-7 are not matched by the Headers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no duplicates:

```
with r as (
      select r.*, count(*) over (partition by idpk_header) as num_items
      from rows r
     )
select r1.idpk_header, r2.idpk_header
from r r1 join
     r r2
     on r1.item_id = r1.item_id and r2.qty = r1.qty and r2.num_items = r1.num_items
group by r1.idpk_header, r2.idpk_header, r1.num_items
having count(*) = r1.num_items;
```

Basically, this does a self-join on the items, so you only get matches.  The `on` validates that the two have the same number of items.  And the `having` guarantees that all match.

Note:  This version returns each match of the header to itself.  That is a nice check.  You can of course filter this out in the `on` or a `where` clause.

If you do have duplicate items, you can simply replace `r` with:

```
select idpk_header, item_id, sum(qty) as qty,
       count(*) over (partition by idpk_header) as num_items
from rows r
group by idpk_header, item_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I woul suggest using a forxml query in order to create the list of items per IDPK. Next I would search for matching item lists and quantities. See following example:

```
DECLARE @Headers TABLE(
IDPK INT,
Description NVARCHAR(100)
)

DECLARE @Rows TABLE(
IDPK INT,
ITEMID NVARCHAR(1),
Qty INT
)

INSERT INTO @Headers VALUES
(1, 'Test1'),
(2, 'Test2'),
(3, 'Test3'),
(4, 'Test4'),
(5, 'Test5')

INSERT INTO @Rows VALUES
 (1, 'A', 10),
 (1, 'B', 20),
 (2, 'A', 10),
 (2, 'B', 20),
 (3, 'A', 5 ),
 (3, 'B', 20),
 (4, 'C', 10),
 (5, 'A', 10),
 (5, 'C', 20)
;

WITH cteHeaderRows AS(
  SELECT IDPK
        ,ItemIDs=STUFF(  
                        (  
                          SELECT ',' + CAST(ITEMID AS VARCHAR(MAX))  
                            FROM @Rows t2   
                            WHERE t2.IDPK = t1.IDPK 
                            ORDER BY ITEMID, QTY  
                            FOR XML PATH('')  
                        ),1,1,''  
                      )
        ,Qtys=STUFF(  
                        (  
                          SELECT ',' + CAST(Qty AS VARCHAR(MAX))  
                            FROM @Rows t2   
                            WHERE t2.IDPK = t1.IDPK   
                            ORDER BY ITEMID, QTY  
                            FOR XML PATH('')  
                        ),1,1,''  
                      )
    FROM @Rows t1  
    GROUP BY IDPK 
),
cteFilter AS(
  SELECT h1.IDPK AS IDPK1, h2.IDPK AS IDPK2
    FROM cteHeaderRows h1
    JOIN cteHeaderRows h2 ON h1.IDPK != h2.IDPK AND h1.ItemIDs = h2.ItemIDs AND h2.Qtys = h1.Qtys
)
SELECT DISTINCT h.IDPK, h.Description, r.ItemID, r.Qty
  FROM @Headers h
  JOIN cteFilter f ON f.IDPK1 = h.IDPK
  JOIN @Rows r ON r.IDPK = f.IDPK1
ORDER BY 1,3,4
```